# Question about deep learning implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm somewhat new to coding but am currently trying to use applied machine learning for the purposes of a biological research project. I am trying to create a neural network that will take an input of a green-channel protein image and guess the red-channel of the same image.

I have a dataset of 10,000 40x40 images that have both red and green channel variants (so 20,000 images in total). To clarify, the images are all grayscale, red channel is just used to signify that proteins stained with a red dye would appear in a different spot than proteins with a green dye. Basically, I want to input an image of one set of proteins and have it guess the location of the other set, then compare with the known paired image of the other set.

I am pretty new to Python and Generative Deep Learning. I understand how it works conceptually, but am wondering what the best architecture for this project would be. I was considering a GAN but am unsure how the discriminator would be trained in this case.
Are there any architectures anyone could recommend I take a look at that I could modify for the purpose of this project?

Comment: you are looking any specific library for this proyect? with best architecture I'm guessing your are talking about the model and the training?

Comment: If you don't have experience with DL algorithm development then my advice would be to start as simple as possible. Jumping into using GANs off the bat is not a great idea since they can be difficult to implement and very temperamental to train. Why not try with a simple autoencoder architecture? You can try to reconstruct your red-channel images from your green-channel inputs.

Comment: A GAN is a "Generative Adversarial Network". GANs generally take noise as an input and generate fake output. For example, A GAN may be used to generate fake images that appear real. It sounds like you're not looking for this, but just a conventional neural network where you specify the input and output.

Comment: @duncster94 I'm an undergrad so I don't get to exactly pick the direction of my project. I don't have experience with DL algorithm development but I'm not making one from scratch - we will likely be modifying an existing one and adapting it to the protein we want to study

Comment: @maurera In a sense I am trying to generate fake red channel images that come close to approximating the known red channel ones. Each red image is paired to a green one so basically we want to train a generator that can be given a novel green channel image and output a reasonably accurate red channel one.

Comment: @ShallowLearning - as far as I understand, this is not what a GAN does. A GAN generator function does not take actual input (it just takes noise). To me it sounds like you want a neural network where input = green channel image and output = red channel image. That is, given x and y, you want to find f such that f(x) =~ y. f is your neural network.

Comment: @maurera Google's pix2pix architecture seems like a GAN specialized at taking image input to the generator: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-pix2pix-gan-for-image-to-image-translation/

Comment: @SiddhantTandon GANs are a general framework for effectively modelling the underlying latent space of the data - they can be used for any task. In the OP's case, they could use an adversarial loss function in order to improve the predicted images (alleviating the blur effect induced by MSE).

Comment: @duncster94 thanks now i understand. I have been looking into it and found some interesting literature on this but related to VAEs. Nonetheless it might help the OP. The model that might help you is the `M2` model in this [link](http://bjlkeng.github.io/posts/semi-supervised-learning-with-variational-autoencoders/) .